# How to show how many enemy has to get killed?

Tags: flash, actionscript

I'm making a game. In the game you kill the enemies. And I set 20 enemies in the screen. When you killed one of them the bar at the top of the screen has to show 19 enemies left. Then 18 enemies left. But it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
if(this.visible==true){
            if(MovieClip(root).kalanDusmanSayisi>=0){
                MovieClip(root).oluDusmanSayisi-1
                this.visible=false
                MovieClip(root).elsilah.gotoAndStop(1)
                if(MovieClip(root).kalanDusmanSayisi==-1){
                MovieClip(root).kalanDusmanSayisi=0
                }
                MovieClip(root).kalanDusmanSayisi=MovieClip(root).toplamDusmanSayisi+MovieClip(root).oluDusmanSayisi-1
                MovieClip(root).rapor.text=MovieClip(root).kalanDusmanSayisi.toString()+ " kişi kaldı!"
            }else{
                removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,dusmanZekasi)
                Mouse.show()
                var rpg:URLRequest=new URLRequest("3. Bölüm.swf")
                var rpgyukleyici:Loader=new Loader()
                rpgyukleyici.load(rpg)
                stage.addChild(rpgyukleyici)
                stage.removeChildAt(0)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Third line:
MovieClip(root).oluDusmanSayisi=MovieClip(root).oluDusmanSayisi-1